# hava i got wrong understanding about AtomicPointer?

Tags: c++, memory-barriers

AtomicPointer is implemented in levelDb as follows :

```
class AtomicPointer {
private:
    void* rep_;
public:
    AtomicPointer() { }
    explicit AtomicPointer(void* p) : rep_(p) {}
    inline void* NoBarrier_Load() const { return rep_; }
    inline void NoBarrier_Store(void* v) { rep_ = v; }

    inline void* Acquire_Load() const {
        void* result = rep_;
        MemoryBarrier();
        return result;
    }

    inline void Release_Store(void* v) {
        MemoryBarrier();    
        rep_ = v;
    }
};
```

Now,i want to do some test,my target is to verify AtomicPointer's Atomic nature ，here is the step:
1. init a struct contains Integers
2. one thread increments the integers by one,and the other thread check the integers are equal or not,when not,report an error.

```
//thread0 callback
unsigned __stdcall apLoad( void * d)
{
    MemoryBarrier();
    while (true)
    {
        B* pb = (B*)ap.Acquire_Load();// B is a struct contains Integer a,b,c
        pb->a ++;
        pb->b ++;
        pb->c ++;
        ap.Release_Store((void*)pb);
    }
}

//thread1 callback
unsigned __stdcall apStore( void * d)
{
    while (true)
    {
        B* pb = (B*)ap.Acquire_Load();
        if(!(pb->a == pb->b && pb->b == pb->c))
        {
            printf("error : %d-%d-%d\r\n",pb->a,pb->b,pb->c);
        }
    }
}
//here is the definition of B
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} B;
```

My question is ,in thread1,how it happens that it will print out "error"!

Answer (score 0):

Only pointer intended to be atomic (not sure if it actually is without full code), contents of strucute isn't. If you have modified pointer - that could have been a different story.

What you intended to do should be done differently. With current structure size you're most likely need a lock or some smart cloning system (e.g. writing changes to copy, then resetting pointer to use that copy).